# Font issue with frontespizio document

Tags: fonts, frontespizio

I have some issues with a frontespizio document. I need to make bold all the text, so following the documentation I made something similar to
`\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\frontfixednamesfont}{%\fontsize{15}{17}\bfseries}}` for every command.

However for the pretitle I need both `\scshape` and `\bfseries` but
`\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\frontpretitlefont}{\fontsize{12}{15}\scschape\bfseries}}` does not work. I tried different combinations and also looking at the source code of the package but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me?

Edit:

```
\usepackage{frontespizio}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength\oddsidemargin{\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 
1in\relax}
\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}


\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\frontinstitutionfont}{%
\fontsize{17}{21}\bfseries}}
\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\frontdivisionfont}{%
\fontsize{15}{20}\bfseries}}
\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\frontpretitlefont}{%
\fontsize{12}{15}\bs}}
\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\fronttitlefont}{%
\fontsize{21}{26}\bfseries}}


\begin{document}

% Frontespizio
\begin{frontespizio}
\Universita{University}
\Dipartimento{Latex}
\Corso{Frontespizio}
\Titoletto{Thesis}
\Titolo{foo}
\Logo[3.5cm]{logo.jpg}
\end{frontespizio}

\IfFileExists{\jobname-frn.pdf}{}{%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex \jobname-frn}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always here you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example  (and self contained) that others can copy and test as is. As your question is here, no-one has any idea what you are doing

Comment: You need a font family that has boldface small caps.

Comment: @egreg Do you have any suggestion? Do you believe it may exist a font that is just the union of ```\scshape``` and ```\bfseries```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computer Modern and also Latin Modern fonts lack boldface small caps.

Choose a font family that has them.

Here I use Libertinus Serif, change to your liking.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

% Frontespizio
\begin{frontespizio}

\begin{Preambolo*}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname front@font\endcsname{\normalfont\bfseries}
\end{Preambolo*}

\Universita{University}
\Dipartimento{Latex}
\Corso{Frontespizio}
\Titoletto{Thesis}
\Titolo{foo}
\Candidato{NM}
\Relatore{SV}
\Annoaccademico{2021-2022}
%\Logo[3.5cm]{logo.jpg}
\end{frontespizio}

\end{document}
```

I made a few changes to your code. In particular, redefining `\front@font` is shorter than redefining all fonts to have `\bfseries`. How do I know this internal? Well, I wrote the package.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, professor Gregorio. I made both my thesis using your package, I really appreciate it. Also when I posted this question I was really in lack of time because of the graduation and your answer let me save a lot of time.